# How to get access to private field via square brackets in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, private, class-fields

This code works:

```js
class Test {
  #field

  get field() {
    return this.#field;
  }
}
```

But if I want to **calculate field name** I have to use square brackets but it doesn't work:

```js
class Test {
  #field;

  get field() {
    return this['#field'];
  }
}
```

Is there any way to get private field with calculated name?

Comment: What do you mean by "calculated name"?  Your example is using a static string.

Comment: It's probable that this is an abstraction of the actual code that demonstrates the issue. I'm wondering if the shim that OP is using has documented this behavior. It looks like this is a [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) with multiple implementations. What environment are you using?

Comment: The `#` for private class member is still experimental and shouldn't be used for production systems.  (Firefox doesn't support it) Also, it's not intended to be used in `[]`. If you want to have dynamic fields, you could do `this.#fields['myfield'];` where `#fields` was declared like `#fields = {field1: 1, field2: "a"};`.

Comment: Quote from the [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields#private-syntax): "There are no private computed property names: `#foo` is a private identifier, and `#[foo]` is a syntax error."

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. From the [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields#private-syntax):

> There are no private computed property names: `#foo` is a private identifier, and `#[foo]` is a syntax error.

and [its FAQ](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields/blob/master/PRIVATE_SYNTAX_FAQ.md#why-doesnt-thisx-access-the-private-field-named-x-given-that-thisx-does):

> ### Why doesn't `this['#x']` access the private field named `#x`, given that `this.#x` does?
>
> 1. This would complicate property access semantics.
> 2. Dynamic access to private fields is contrary to the notion of 'private'. E.g. this is concerning:
>
> ```js
> class Dict extends null {
>   #data = something_secret;
>   add(key, value) {
>     this[key] = value;
>   }
>   get(key) {
>     return this[key];
>   }
> }
>
> (new Dict).get('#data'); // returns something_secret
> ```
>
> #### But doesn't giving `this.#x` and `this['#x']` different semantics break an invariant of current syntax?
>
> Not exactly, but it is a concern. `this.#x` has never previously been
> legal syntax, so from one point of view there can be no invariant
> regarding it.
>
> On the other hand, it might be surprising that they differ, and this
> is a downside of the current proposal.

See also [this issue](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields/issues/257).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it is a problem to hand over a string which has a special meaning.

If really necessary, you evaluate a string.

```js
class Test {
    #field = 'foo';

    get field() {
        return eval('this.' +'#field');
    }
}

console.log(new Test().field)
```